# Login system wont login

Tags: php, sql, database, authentication

So, I have the following code which is supposed to work as a login system. When I enter the details that are supposed to be entered, it still comes up with "Wrong details. Please try again". This is probably a stupid basic bug but I am not that fluent with PHP yet.

```
<?php

$dbc = mysqli_connect("hostaddress","user","pass") or 
      die("Could not connect to server". mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_select_db($dbc, "dbname") or die("could not connect to the database");

//Check if the login form has been submitted;

if(isset($_POST["go"])) {
      $addr = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, htmlentities($_POST["e_address"]));
      $psw = SHA1 ($_POST["u_pass"]); //Using sha1() to encrypt passwords

      //query to check if the email address and password match;
      $q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE address='$addr' AND pass='$psw'";

      //run the query and store result;
      $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

      //Make sure we have a positive result;
      if($res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q)) {
        //Start a session;
        session_start();

        //Creating a log session variable that will persist through pages;
        $_SESSION["log"] = "in";

        //Redirecting to restricted page;
        header("location: restricted.php");

      } else {
        //Create an error message;
        $error = "Wrong details. Please try again";
      }

} //End isset go

?>

<form method="post" action="#">

    <p><label for="e_address">Email Address:</label></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="e_address" value="" placeholder="Email Address" maxlength="30"></p>
    <p><label for="u_pass">Password:</label></p>
    <p><input type="password" name="u_pass" value="" placeholder="Password"   maxlength="12"></p>
<p><button type="submit" name="go">Log me in</button></p>
</form>

<!-- Error Displayer -->
<p><strong><?php if(isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?></strong></p>
```

Comment: if($res = mysqli_query($dbc, $q)) { should be a double = sign but this is always going to return true because you are checking to see if they result variable is the same twice

Comment: Ryan, you have asked five questions on this site, and each of those questions share a common theme: they contain no indication that you performed any debugging on your own before posting here. Debugging is an integral part of the software development process. I strongly suggest that you spend time learning how to debug instead of relying on the SO developers to do your job for you. We can help with the especially difficult problems, but learning to identify and overcome these basic difficulties should be part of your daily process.

Comment: You should also check up on these topics: 1) mysql(i)_* functions are outdated, 2) proper login mechanisms use many rounds of salted hashing, are time-constant, etc...

Comment: @LeventePánczél `mysqli_*` functions aren't deprecated.  Only `mysql_*` functions are.  Some *aliases* for MySQLi are deprecated, but the library as a whole is fine.  That said, I agree this is not the right way to do authentication.

Comment: @BaconBits: I did not write "deprecated". I think all DB-specific functions are outdated and not be used unless there is an absolute need. I can see that in very rare cases one might need to use mysqli instead of PDO, but one should weigh carefully whther to abandon security and flexibility.

Comment: @LeventePánczél I would say that opinions about which DB connection method you use are out of place when the code presented has actual problems, like SQL injection points caused by relying on `mysqli_real_escape_string()` and string concatenation to build a query instead of using prepared statements. If this code were directly translated to PDO, it wouldn't correct anything.

Comment: @BaconBits: You are right. And all these problems are addressed in the answer that was already present when I commented. In fact this is why I wrote a comment, not an answer; to indicate that I only provide additional guidance. So I expected the OP to use answers to solve the problem in the first place, and then use the comments and "ALSO check up on these topics". Anyways I can't see how flaming on a misinterpretation of a SUGGESTION is going to help anyone; so everybody please feel free to ignore my comments.

Answer (score 0):

try to start with `session_start();` at first line

and try add after the query `or die(__LINE__." ".mysqli_error($dbc))`

and U can use the query without the password and check the password then with php